# Perform an update if action selected is edit

Tags: php

I have a link `<a href='test.php?action=edit&id=$id'>Edit</a>`

If user clicks on this link an update form is displayed, for him/she to update

the `$action=="edit";`

is the action perfomed in this case it must update, how ever its not here in the code

```
if ($action == "edit"){ 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' where id = '$id'"); 
     $sql = mysql_query($result) or die (mysql_error());
}
sql=mysql_query("select * from user where id='$id'");

   while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
 {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
$id = $row['id'];
$first_name = $row['first_name'];
$last_name = $row['last_name'];
$email = $row['email'];
              $result=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' WHERE id=$id");
              $sql = mysql_query($result) or die (mysql_error());

ho("<form name='edit' method='post' action='?action=edit'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='?action=edit'>");
echo("<table class=main cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 width=50%>");
echo("<tr><td>Name: </td><td align='right'><input type='text'  name='first_name' value='$first_name'></td></tr>");
echo("<tr><td>Surname: </td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='last_name' value='$last_name'></td></tr>");
echo("<tr><td>Email: </td><td align='right'><input type='text'  name='email' value='$email'></td></tr>");
echo("<tr><td></td><td><div align='right'><input type='submit'></div></td></tr>");
echo("</table>");
 }
}
```

Is there a way to get this query to return a value cause now it seems to be not workng...

Im suspecting this line

```
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' WHERE id=$id");
                  $sql = mysql_query($result) or die (mysql_error());
```

cause if I add the

```
where id = '$id'
```

it ruturns You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

if the is removed

```
where id = $id
```

it returns "Query was empty"  I need help Ive been working on this it not working right

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' where id = '$id'"); 
$sql = mysql_query($result) or die (mysql_error());
```

You should just do this:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE user SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' where id = '$id'"); 
 mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: This works thank you, but still cant update the error is gone though any suggestions?

Comment: -1 For not pointing out the obvious SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Do either of the followings:

change

```
if ($action == "edit"){
```

to

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "edit"){
```

and also remove

```
echo("<input type='hidden' name='?action=edit'>");
```

**UPADTE**

Test this instead of all you codes:

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "edit"){
    if ($_POST['performEdit'] == 'Yes') { 
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $result=mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `first_name`='$first_name', `last_name`='$last_name', `email`='$email' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
        if(!$result){
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    }
    $row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id`='$id' LIMIT 0, 1"));
    $id = $row['id'];
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    $email = $row['email'];

    echo "<form name='edit' method='post' action='test.php?action=edit'>
            <input type='hidden' name='performEdit' value='Yes'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
            <table class=main cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 width=50%>
                <tr><td>Name: </td><td align='right'><input type='text'  name='first_name' value='$first_name'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Surname: </td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='last_name' value='$last_name'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email: </td><td align='right'><input type='text'  name='email' value='$email'></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><div align='right'><input type='submit'></div></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>");
}
```

**In general, DO NOT use MySQL anymore, use MySQLi instead.**

Comment: Why Am I removing this echo("<input type='hidden' name='?action=edit'>"); ?

Comment: Because you are already sending the `action` parameter in `echo("<form name='edit' method='post' action='test.php?action=edit'>");`

Comment: I dont know whats wrong now savafa it runs well everythng seems ok no errors are showing maybe its my form is there an improvement that you can recommend?

Comment: Edit your question and add the new code at the end of it. Do not remove from your initial post but, put a EDIT part after what you have right now.

Comment: See the **UPDATE** section in my answer.

Comment: @Jesty, if my answer is working for you, then way not accepting it as the answer by clicking on the *tick sign* below the post score ;)